# Angular - how custom filter really works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to implement my own filter, and I've found this working example http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

But I don't understand a few things:

1) in the following code, where it comes from the `clients` array ? I see the `$scope.clients` field, but I can't see how it is being injected inside the filter function

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('companyFilter', [function () {
        return function (clients, selectedCompany) { .....
```

2) what is `filtered` ? Is it just a name/alias for filtered `clients` inside `()` ?

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | companyFilter:selectedCompany)">
```

3) I suppose the following functions are that custom filter, but that filter expects the `clients` array and some `ID`, but that functions doesn't match that criteria.

```
_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, id)
_.without($scope.selectedCompany, id)
_.pluck($scope.companyList, 'id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter takes what it was applied to as first parameter, so when you do "smth | filter", smth will be passed as first parameter to filter, the second parameter is what you added after ':', e.g. : "smth | filter:params".
And filter function returns the actual filter result.

So in this case:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | companyFilter:selectedCompany)">
```

filter will take an array 'clients' with parameter 'selectedCompany', return an array witch will be passed to ng-repeat.

Comment: thanks - but what if I'd like to put more arguments to my filter ?

Comment: hm. as documentation says there is only one parameter and 2 options: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

So you can use several ways here, depending what exactly what you need:

-- create a service, with is singleton, inject it as dependency into filter and pass params through it.

-- create multiple filters and chain them, smth like: ng-repeat="item in items = (smthing |filter1:param1 | filter2:param2 | ..)"

-- so something in your controller.